# How to convert an integer declared as a string to an int type?

Tags: c++, c++11

I tried this solution but it doesn't work.

```
string mystring = "77";
int mynum = atoi(mystring);
```

> error: cannot convert ‘std::string {aka std::basic_string}’ to ‘const char*’ for argument ‘1’ to ‘int atoi(const char*)’
>     int mynum = atoi(mystring);

Answer (score 2):

If you use `std::string` you may use `atoi` with `std::string::c_str()` method, or directly by using `std::stoi`:

```
int val = std::stoi(mystring);
```

[std::stoi reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/stoi/)

With `boost` you may use `boost::lexical_cast`:

```
int val = boost::lexical_cast<int>(mystring);
```

[boost::lexical_cast reference](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_lexical_cast.html)

Note, that `atoi` is a history already, mainly because it is old `C` standard library function. Modern code is using `lexical_cast` or `stoi`.

Comment: When I use std::stoi, I get error saying 'stoi' is not a member od 'std'.

Comment: @FreeSlave So did you include `string` and turned on `c++11` in your compiler? Your question is marked `c++11` tag so you must know what it is and how to turn it on.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
string mystring = "77";
int mynum = atoi(mystring.c_str());
```

or in C++11:

```
string mystring = "77";
int mynum = stoi(mystring);
```

Comment: stoi not working.
error: ‘stoi’ was not declared in this scope.

Comment: So did you include `string` and turned on `c++11` in your compiler? Your question is marked `c++11` tag so you must know what it is and how to turn it on.

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
int mynum = atoi(mystring.c_str());
```